# Reflective Language for Symbolical Computations

Tags: reflection, programming-languages, symbolic-math, computer-algebra-systems

I'm seeking for a language that operates on programs, written in that very language. That is a language whose programs are the primary (possibly the only) objects of that language.

Something like self-program transformation language, made solely with this point of view in mind.

Motivation is the following:

Having a program P1 meant to compute Real -> Real I want to have a program P2 which would take P1 and transform it to a symbolical derivative (or an antiderivative) of P1. Obviously P2 might fail to do a proper work on most of the inputs.

One might view it as a pattern matching against lambdas. But a very convenient pattern matching.

Comment: What languages does your research suggest? What languages have you found that don't quite fit the bill, and why?

Comment: @Marcin I've tried pure, but it's representation for reflection is clumsy. For example if-then-else and guards are represented distinctly.

Comment: So, update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

lisp/scheme/racket. or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think [C# Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) (or [F# quotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233212.aspx)) could be used for this. They are by far not the primary (or the only) objects of those languages but I they should let you do this nicely.